# Format date in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, date, format

I have a date in this format "2017-06-26 10:21:25.88785". My purpose is to show this kind of format 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss', and put this date into a ng-table. So, I write in my ng-table

```
{{::fondo.aggTms | date:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'}}
```

Where fondo is my variable and aggTms is the attribute of the main variable.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work, and in my table is shown the first (wrong) format.
Anyone could help me?

Comment: try 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'

Comment: see this works https://plnkr.co/edit/VlncmSbKi95EwmuMUpp2?p=preview

Comment: It doesn't work. If it could help, the part of code where the {{::fondo.aggTms | date:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'}} is written come from a popover...

Comment: can you make a snippet  with more code so that it will be more clear.

Comment: I suppose that more code is not helpfull. I tried to replace your data with my data in your plunker, and it does not work, you can check it. It seems to be that the input format "2017-06-26 10:21:25.88785" is not 'good'

Comment: If I put in this way a T and a Z 2017-06-26T10:21:25.88785Z it works..... why? (also if I remove final Z...)

Comment: I'm assuming 25.88785 is the number of seconds? If so you should round that number to the nearest second for this to work.

Comment: Hi William. If I remove the decimal part, it doesn't work. I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try rounding of last seconds part Then covert it into date & then try the angular filter. the function to be called in place of fondo.aggTms is

```
$scope.toDate = function(date){
    var res = date.split(":");
    var last = window.Math.round(res[2]);
    var datestring = res[0]+':'+res[1]+':'+last;
    var d = new Date(datestring);
    return d;
}

{{::toDate(fondo.aggTms) | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}
```

This is the working plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/7OHqUmxnjfs89mCMCF3M?p=preview

Now this's only valid if you're considering that last part as seconds in decimal.